# nltk.tokenize.casual and emojis

Tags: python, tokenize

I am trying to tokenise a simple string:

Here is a smiling face: !

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from nltk.tokenize.casual import TweetTokenizer

s = u"Here is a smiling face: !"

s1 = TweetTokenizer().tokenize(s)
print (s1)
```

And here is what I get:

```
[u'Here', u'is', u'a', u'smiling', u'face', u':', u'\ud83d', u'\ude00', u'!']
```

Shouldnt the smiley face come back as ONE token (is this due to a 'narrow-build'?)? 
And how am I to combine the \ud83d and the \ude00 and print them so I can see that the results contained a smiley face???

I am using Python 2.7 and NLTK 3.0.5 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Thanks.

Comment: I used Python 2.7 and NLTK 3.2.4, and got the problem you described. With Python 3.5 the smiley is processed as one token. Do you have the possibility of using Python 3.5 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Did you try with NLTK 3.2.4? even for me, it worked with Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can simply upgrade your `NLTK` and it should work.

```
# upgrade nltk
pip install nltk --upgrade
```

If it still doesn't work then probably it's a good time to switch to `Python3` as supports for `Python2` and related libraries are not being maintained.